# Calculating average speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed

The car drove a third of the entire road with a speed of v<sub>1</sub> = 46 km/h.
After that, a quarter of the time it drove at a speed 1.5 times greater than the average speed during the entire journey.
The last part of the road the car traveled at a speed of 2v<sub>1</sub>.
Find the maximum value of the car's speed during the entire journey.
[image: Car driving]

My questions is how we calculate average speed?

In books it says average speed is s/t, but in this case can we use formulas like
v_average = (1/3*v<sub>1</sub>  + 1/4*v*1.5 + 5/12*v<sub>1</sub>)/3